# Highlighting the part of a line graph that has the highest slope in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset contains 2 variables **Y and X**. Y was measured every 1.0 seconds.

My Data:

```
 dput(Dataexample)
structure(list(X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 
78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 
108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 
121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 
134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 
147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 
160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 
173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 
186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 
199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 
212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 
225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 
238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 
251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 
264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 
277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 
290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 
303, 304, 305, 306), Y = c(71756.2344, 71745.85, 70882.42, 71025.61, 
70539.02, 70602.3047, 70811.87, 70514.125, 69998.63, 70531.76, 
70424.9141, 70663.51, 70075.375, 69731.0859, 70029.74, 70519.31, 
69858.63, 69987.23, 70080.56, 69970.63, 69829.6, 69872.12, 69775.68, 
69679.24, 69814.05, 69639.84, 69645.02, 69344.35, 69430.41, 70078.49, 
69239.65, 69734.1953, 69736.27, 69549.63, 69506.0859, 69108, 
69669.91, 69516.45, 69490.54, 69609.77, 69314.29, 69454.25, 69590.07, 
69721.76, 69525.79, 69736.27, 69303.92, 69171.23, 69294.59, 69430.41, 
69457.36, 69462.54, 69144.27, 69590.07, 69446.99, 70083.67, 69358.87, 
69800.56, 69680.28, 69332.95, 69723.83, 69942.63, 69772.56, 69969.59, 
69808.86, 70043.23, 70208.13, 70077.45, 69856.56, 70423.875, 
69490.54, 69984.12, 70175.98, 70192.58, 70279.7, 70480.93, 70594, 
70792.16, 70234.06, 70165.61, 70249.62, 70564.95, 70403.13, 70444.625, 
70426.99, 69907.375, 70327.4141, 70686.3359, 70473.67, 71031.83, 
70864.78, 70710.1953, 70691.52, 70703.97, 70826.39, 70708.12, 
70595.04, 70946.75, 71319.27, 70977.875, 70475.74, 70612.68, 
70680.11, 70527.61, 70461.22, 70877.2344, 70631.35, 70723.68, 
70677, 70433.21, 70306.6641, 71246.63, 70375.125, 70416.62, 70150.0547, 
70733.0156, 70583.63, 70866.86, 70580.5156, 70433.21, 70377.2, 
70114.79, 70347.12, 70613.71, 70576.37, 70599.19, 70407.28, 70581.5547, 
70650.02, 71122.11, 70909.4, 70694.63, 71076.45, 70650.02, 71133.52, 
70810.83, 71240.41, 70630.31, 71144.94, 71493.63, 71117.95, 71374.28, 
71143.9, 70805.64, 71349.375, 71208.2344, 71322.39, 71727.1641, 
71060.88, 71546.56, 71569.4, 70984.1, 72032.37, 71573.55, 71787.375, 
71469.76, 71398.15, 71683.57, 71709.52, 71637.9, 71556.9453, 
71870.4141, 71612.99, 71953.47, 71515.43, 71315.125, 72007.4453, 
72021.9844, 71549.68, 72001.22, 71359.75, 71775.95, 72327.23, 
71949.31, 71844.47, 71857.96, 72128.9141, 72147.6, 71501.94, 
72268.05, 72104, 72217.1641, 72253.51, 72198.48, 72908.78, 72084.27, 
72653.29, 72431.06, 72858.92, 72512.0547, 72632.5156, 72700.02, 
72335.53, 72713.52, 73065.62, 72818.42, 73004.3359, 72458.06, 
73436.48, 73231.82, 73002.26, 73313.89, 73213.125, 72980.4453, 
72948.25, 73106.13, 72931.625, 73409.47, 73057.31, 73141.4453, 
73218.32, 73216.24, 73273.375, 73701.42, 73486.35, 72574.37, 
73229.74, 73576.74, 73195.46, 73697.2656, 73115.48, 73065.62, 
73062.5, 73111.32, 73988.23, 73619.3359, 73874.95, 73683.76, 
73674.41, 73550.7656, 74166.9844, 73875.99, 74013.17, 74092.16, 
73872.875, 74015.25, 73984.07, 73911.33, 73606.87, 74082.8, 73866.64, 
74550.53, 74271.95, 73980.95, 74502.71, 74901.92, 74753.25, 74310.4141, 
75178.51, 74748.05, 74756.37, 75194.1, 74797.95, 75531.0547, 
75549.77, 75293.94, 75378.17, 75457.21, 75676.67, 76087.56, 76141.6641, 
76008.5, 76241.55, 76585.96, 76091.73, 76880.4844, 76898.18, 
77005.38, 77080.32, 77548.78, 77337.4453, 77000.18, 77448.8359, 
76997.0547, 77314.54, 77919.47, 77185.46, 78127.75, 77464.45, 
78349.59, 77824.71, 77465.49, 77818.46, 78140.25, 78547.51, 77850.74, 
78236.06, 78341.2656, 78104.8359, 78464.17, 77888.23, 78392.3, 
78686.0547, 78149.625, 78623.5547, 78672.5156, 78810.03, 78498.55, 
78652.72, 78717.31, 78831.91, 78882.96, 78715.23, 78499.5859, 
78892.3359, 78372.51)), row.names = c(NA, -306L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have used `ggplot` to plot the data and used a loop to calculate the average slope within a moving 60-second-window for the entire duration of the dataset to find the 60 consecutive seconds where the slope is greatest.

Code:

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

Dataexample<- read_csv("HF-6.csv", skip = 3) 
Dataexample<- head(Dataexample, -1)

Dataexample$X <- as.numeric(Dataexample$X)

df <- data.frame(Dataexample)
 

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=1)) +
  geom_line()


slopes <- rep(NA, nrow(Dataexample)-59)
for( i in 1:length(slopes)){
  slopes[i] <- lm(Y ~ X, data=Dataexample[i:(i+59), ])$coefficients[2]
}

print(slopes)

which.max(slopes)
max(slopes)
```

[image: Plot]

**My questions is how can I then take the results of my loop that show the consecutive 60 seconds where the slope is highest and change the color of the line in the plot during those 60 seconds to highlight where slope is greatest.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
maxslope_ind <- which.max(slope)
Dataexample$highlight <- ifelse(Dataexample$X %in% maxslope_ind:(maxslope_ind+59), 1, 0)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Dataexample, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=as.factor(highlight)), show.legend=FALSE) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can make it not rely on the explicit value of 234 in `Dataexample$highlight <- ifelse(Dataexample$X %in% 234:(234+59), 1, 0)`  for example can I call the return of `which.max` so i can use the script on other data?

Comment: I used `maxslope<- which.max(slopes)` and then
`maxslope <- as.data.frame(maxslope)` to change `which.max` into a data frame and then used `Dataexample$highlight <- ifelse(Dataexample$X %in% as.numeric(maxslope$maxslope):(as.numeric(maxslope$maxslope)+59), 1, 0)` and it seems to work

Comment: I updated the answer to something slightly simpler than your solution, though the idea is very much the same.  The difference is that you don't need to turn the `max slope` object into a data frame.